# Navigate on button click using protected routes in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have `App.js` which looks like this

```
<Router>
     <Routes>
         <Route element={<AnonymousUserRoute />}>
              <Route path='/user/login' element={<UserLoginScreen />}/>
         </Route>
         <Route element={<ProtectedUserRoute />} >
              <Route path='/' element={<HomeScreen />} exact />
         </Route>
     </Routes>
</Router>
```

`ProtectedUserRoute.js`

```
function ProtectedUserRoute() {
    const loginPageLink = "/user/login";
    const token = //getting from local storage

    return (
        token ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to={loginPageLink} replace />
    );
};
```

`AnonymousUserRoute.js`

```
function AnonymousUserRoute() {
    const homePageLink = "/";
    const token = //getting from local storage

    return (
        token ? <Navigate to={homePageLink} replace /> : <Outlet />
    );
};
```

`Login.js`

```
function UserLoginScreen() {
    ...
    const handleLoginClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        dispatch(loginUser(email, password));
        navigate('/');
    }
    ...
}
```

The problem I am facing is that, once `handleLoginClick` is clicked, the `navigate` function is not redirecting me to home screen immediately because `ProtectedUserRoute` doesn't allow i think. But upon refreshing the page, my route identifies that there is a token in local storage and redirects to home screen. How can i ensure, navigation happens without refresh here ?

**EDIT**

`reducers.js`

```
export const userLoginReducer = (state = { userDetails: { isLoggedIn: false } }, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
            return { loading: true }
        case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            return { loading: false, isLoggedIn: action.payload }
        case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
            return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

`actions.js`

```
export const loginUser = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
    const loginUrl = //loginUrl
    try {
        dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST })
        
        const loginData = { email: email, password: password }
        const config = { headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json'} }
        const { data } = await axios.post(loginUrl, loginData, config)
        
        dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: true })
        
        storeUserLoggedInDetailsInLocalStorage(data.tokens); //calling a function which stores in localstorage. Nothing else done here.
    } catch(error) {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail
                    ? error.response.data.detail
                    : error.message
        })
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I have this `isLoggedIn` boolean value in `Login` screen which will be set to `true` once user is logged in. Below is the snippet

```
const userDetails = useSelector(state => state.userDetails)
const { isLoggedIn } = userDetails
```

**EDIT 2:**
`store.js`

```
const userDetailsFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('userDetails') ? 
                         JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userDetails')) : {}

const reducer = combineReducers({
    userDetails: userLoginReducer,
})

const persistedState = {
    userDetails: {
        isLoggedIn: userDetailsFromStorage.isLoggedIn ?? false
    }
}

const middleWare = [thunk]

const store = createStore(reducer, persistedState, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleWare)));

export default store
```

Comment: I guess that `//getting from some function` is the problem. Maybe this function is async

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, i have updated from where i am getting token. Can you suggest any ways here ?

Comment: My guess here is that the `loginUser(email, password)` action is asynchronous and hasn't set any authentication state in the app anywhere when the `handleLoginClick` handler happily chugs along and calls `navigate("/")`. Please [edit] to include ***all*** the relevant code you are working with here as part of your complete [mcve]. Can you share your redux code that is handling the login flow, and anything else from app root down through the routes you've shown?

Comment: @DrewReese, i've added the redux code. Please let me know if anything else is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loginUser` is an asynchronous action and you *should* be able to `await` it to resolve/reject.

Something similar to the following example:

```js
function UserLoginScreen() {
  ...

  const handleLoginClick = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      await dispatch(loginUser(email, password));
      navigate('/');
    } catch(error) {
      // handle or ignore errors/rejections
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

### Demo

[image: Edit navigate-on-button-click-using-protected-routes-in-react]

The `loginUser` action *may* need to re-throw any errors it catches so UI that is waiting can catch and handle it in the UI, for example if you wanted to set some local error state or trigger a toast message to the user.

Comment: I tried this but still not working. I'm getting the following squiggles in vscode. `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.`

Comment: @Srivatsa How have you setup/configured the Redux store? Alternatively, have you considered moving to [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) that handles asynchronous actions much better and requires about 50% less Redux code on your part?

Comment: I've added code as to how i've configured the redux store. Please check it out. I have not researched about redux-toolkit yet. I'll put it under my bucket :)

Comment: @Srivatsa Thanks, I think that may be enough to recreate enough of the frontend UI to check what else might be going on. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @Srivatsa Sorry for delay. I was able to create a running [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/navigate-on-button-click-using-protected-routes-in-react-4z5tmr) demo of your code and my suggested solution here appears to work as I was expecting. Please take a look when you have time.

Comment: I tried to encapsulate my navigation in an useEffect hook, outside of the `handleLoginClick` and its working. Please advice if this is the right way to do it.
```useEffect(() => { if(isLoggedIn === true) { navigate("/"); } }, [isLoggedIn, navigate])
```
And thanks for the solution. Will try it as well!

Comment: @Srivatsa I think it's preferred (*just my opinion*) to keep the logic together in the callback handler, but splitting it out into a separate side-effect should work as well. I can't say one is objectively better than the other. The main difference is the need to declare a local state and effect to handle it outside the callback, which is more moving parts, and this delays the navigation at least one additional render cycle since you need to update the state to trigger a rerender so the effect can run.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254316/discussion-between-srivatsa-and-drew-reese).